# What is Analog Ground in UDA1334A?

Tags: arduino, audio, dac, i2s

I purchased Adafruit's UDA1334A I2S Stereo DAC, and I'm trying to figure out how to wire it to speakers. I see I have the Lout and Rout pins, which I suppose is the positive for the left and right speakers, and between them I have AGND pin. Should I connect this to the ground of both speakers?

Comment: You can see how the audio jack is connected here: https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/48419

Comment: What does the manual say how to connect it? And which kind of speakers do you mean, just speakers, or speakers with amplifier and line level audio input?

Comment: don't you need an amplifier?

Comment: @Justme, They're 5W 4Ohm speakers with just two wires, no amplifier.

Comment: @DamienD, I don't know how to read these schemas...

Comment: The Adafruit description says it has "line level" output - you are unlikely to get a useful sound level if you try to drive bare speakers - you will need an audio power amplifier.  It will probably be OK driving headphones directly.

Comment: The schema has the headphone jack connected to AGND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Adafruit DAC module has a line level output.

It can be connected to an amplifier line level input.

It can barely drive headphones but it's not meant for it.

It cannot drive speakers directly, you need a speaker amplifier for that.

Comment: Isn't it an amplifier itself?

Comment: @YoavKlein No, it never reads anywhere that it has an amplifier. It is a DAC with line level audio output.

Comment: thanks! What kind of product do I need to in order to connect speakers to this?

Comment: An amplifier that takes in line level audio and can drive speakers. I think that is the most generic what I can say as basically asking and suggesting for product to buy is off-topic.